# Qualities of Even Permutation Groups

Tags: permutations

I need some help figuring out some qualities of even permutation groups.
Consider $E_n$ to be a subset of the bijection set $S_n$ (bijections over
$[n]$) that consists of all even permutations. I want to show that there
are no trivial normal subgroups of $E_5$ (as in, if $E_5$ has a normal
subgroup, it must be either $(e)$ or $E_5$ itself). I was wondering if it
might be best to use a version of Sylow's Theorem and then use the properties
of the order of $E_5$ to suggests something about the quality of $E_5$'s
subgroups. That being said, I cannot be sure if this is an appropriate method.

Comment: The usual notation is $A_n$, the [alternating group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group).

Comment: The simplest approach I know uses the Class Equation. Are you familiar with that result?

Comment: Where you wrote "no trivial normal subgroups" did you mean "no non-trivial normal subgroups"? ${}\qquad{}$